# Why are iPads so expensive at amazon?

Tags: ipad, hardware-recommendation

I have some money at my amazon account that don't seem to be transferable to Europe so I was thinking about redeeming them and buying an iPad. After a small research I have found out following things :

1. Compared with prices at apple site, amazon is very expensive. For example, a basic 16 GB 3G model costs $629 at apple site while starting at $850 at amazon. Does this have something to do with the shortage of iPads now (i.e. there will be a price drop as soon as they become available), or are there some taxes not included in the apple price that make amazon prices higher in general ?
2. Both at apple and at amazon there is a provider to choose when selecting a 3G model (AT&T vs. Verizon). I live in Austria, Europe and would probably use some of the local providers, if at all. Do you think it is possible, are there some contracts one has to sign or anything that would prevent me from that ? I would mainly use the iPad for development and I really would want one with GPS, having a 3G as an option is more of a nice-to-have for me. Still it's interesting to know whether it's somehow blocked for US market or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Just looking at [the entry on amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002C74BNG), it appears to be because Amazon doesn't offer it directly, but sellers that use Amazon's store front do.  They are likely selling them above Apple's price because of the high demand vs. lack of supply.
2. You can buy one of the 3G models without a contract; the main reason you have to choose a provider is because of the different wireless technologies (GSM vs. CDMA).  This is unchanged from the original iPad (I did not have to buy/enter into a contract with it).

Comment: makes sense, then I'll wait some time and probably go for it. thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

1. If you follow the **Available from these sellers** link you'll see that none of them are actually sold by Amazon; rather, they're sold by independent resellers who are marking them up because they can.
2. The GSM version (AT&T) *should* work fine there, I know I've heard of people doing it. I can't guarantee it, though, as it may depend on your carrier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the iPad in another country, get the AT&T model. The Verizon model uses CDMA and is not compatible with most carriers, but the AT&T model uses GSM, which is used by almost all carriers. There is no contract, but you will need to get a different SIM card which works with the carrier you choose.

As far as I know, Amazon raised the price to increase profit, and will eventually lower the price to match competitors.